# Is there a way to normalize the following data using R/Python?

Tags: python, r, bioinformatics, normalization

In R, using the package Immunarch, one can observe the distribution of CDR3 lengths across multiple datasets using the following function:

```
repExplore(immdata1$data, .method = "len", .col = "aa") %\>% vis()
```

These are the number of samples in each dataset classed under immdata1:

- `[2577],
- [863],
- [1455],
- [1170],
- [8241],
- [337],
- [2586],
- [1637],
- [3038],
- [2296],
- [500],
- [1727],
- [3458],
- [9335],
- [3479],
- [3027],
- [22626],
- [1453],
- [2081],
- [841],
- [2293],
- [2797],
- [5805]

As you can see one dataset has significantly more samples (22626) than the others.

Is there a way to add normalisation to the Immunarch function, or is there another package that would be useful in R, or is there something I can do with Python.

Have not tried anything, just a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

add this row of data to a list and call it data then apply this:

```
result = [item[0] for item in data]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).